# Magento order status

Tags: magento-1.9

we are using marketplace extension so seller can able to generate invoice their Dashboard

so we are using this code for generate invoice

```
 $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();
```

But after that it automatically order status Complete. So that i change in this way

```
$shipment->getOrder()->setState('invoice');


                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();
```

After that i add some custom order status like Shipement when i click it automatically change complete instaed of shipement

**Shipment controller**

```
public function shipementorderAction(){
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'shipement');
                $order->setStatus('shipement');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 

                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
                //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


                }
```

[image]

i don't know what is the problem?

Comment: If you create invoice & shipping to order all qty then order status must completed and it is magento default functionality

Comment: how to change that

Comment: is it automatically change complete status after create shipment right?

Comment: once create invoice that state change invoiced after i click shipment it shows complete

Comment: after i click shipment it shows invoice right

Comment: after i click shipment it shows complete but i need shipment

Comment: can you tell me your order status after invoice created?

Comment: 1.Pending, 2.Processing, 3. invoice, 4.shipement . 5.COmplete(manully)

Comment: but you need : 1.Pending, 2.Processing, 3. invoice, 4.shipement right after shipment create

Comment: After invoice i have button called shipment if i click it should change shipement

Comment: While clicking invoice it generated invoice slip as well as shipping slip it's not a problem status only problem

Comment: Have you added shipment generate code qus?

Comment: Check my updated question i add shipment code

Comment: In magento order state & status two field but your case :  status => shipment & state => ???

Comment: state also shipment i created custom status check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Below are the status's you can use

```
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```

Code for updating the status.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid, 'increment_id');
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$order->save();
```

Above code will update all the status's except COMPLETE Status. As Order becomes complete only when invoice and shipment is created. Once invoice and shipment is created order will automatically changed to Complete.

so for that you can use below code.

Create Invoice

```
$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice()
                 ->setTransactionId($order->getId())
                 ->addComment($comment)
                 ->register()
                 ->pay();

$transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                 ->addObject($invoice)
                 ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transaction_save->save();
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Also visit this link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/how-to-define-the-order-status-after-creating-an-invoice

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this:**

Override order model file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` in local or community

**OR**

copy core `Order.php` file in local folder `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model`

After replace code in function `_checkState()` from

```
protected function _checkState()
{
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $userNotification = $this->hasCustomerNoteNotify() ? $this->getCustomerNoteNotify() : null;

    if (!$this->isCanceled()
        && !$this->canUnhold()
        && !$this->canInvoice()
        && !$this->canShip()) {
        if (0 == $this->getBaseGrandTotal() || $this->canCreditmemo()) {
            if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_COMPLETE) {
                $this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);
            }
        }
        /**
         * Order can be closed just in case when we have refunded amount.
         * In case of "0" grand total order checking ForcedCanCreditmemo flag
         */
        elseif (floatval($this->getTotalRefunded()) || (!$this->getTotalRefunded()
            && $this->hasForcedCanCreditmemo())
        ) {
            if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_CLOSED) {
                $this->_setState(self::STATE_CLOSED, true, '', $userNotification);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($this->getState() == self::STATE_NEW && $this->getIsInProcess()) {
        $this->setState(self::STATE_PROCESSING, true, '', $userNotification);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

**To**

```
protected function _checkState()
{
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $userNotification = $this->hasCustomerNoteNotify() ? $this->getCustomerNoteNotify() : null;

    if (!$this->isCanceled()
        && !$this->canUnhold()
        && !$this->canInvoice()
        && !$this->canShip()) {
        if (0 == $this->getBaseGrandTotal() || $this->canCreditmemo()) {
            if ($this->getState() == 'invoice') {
                $this->_setState('shipment', true, '', $userNotification);
            }
            elseif ($this->getState() == 'shipment') {
                $this->_setState('shipment', true, '', $userNotification);
            }
            elseif ($this->getState() == 'Shipment') {
                $this->_setState('Shipment', true, '', $userNotification);
            }elseif($this->getState() !== self::STATE_COMPLETE) {
                $this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);
            }

        }
        /**
         * Order can be closed just in case when we have refunded amount.
         * In case of "0" grand total order checking ForcedCanCreditmemo flag
         */
        elseif (floatval($this->getTotalRefunded()) || (!$this->getTotalRefunded()
            && $this->hasForcedCanCreditmemo())
        ) {
            if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_CLOSED) {
                $this->_setState(self::STATE_CLOSED, true, '', $userNotification);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($this->getState() == self::STATE_NEW && $this->getIsInProcess()) {
        $this->setState(self::STATE_PROCESSING, true, '', $userNotification);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: No change same thing only invoice status also not showing

Comment: invoice status changed but if i click shipment it automatically complete

Comment: comment code : $this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification) and try again for testing

Comment: After click shipment status not showing